# How do I test if my iterator is equal to a location

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

The following code compiles but when I run the exe it will pass the end of the vector and I get a run error. These two lines are defined in the constructors.

```
vector< myObj > myVect;
vector< myObj >::iterator myVectit = myVect.begin();
```

A method is called that increments the iterator. It seems to work fine until ti get to the end of its objects.

```
myVectit++;
if(myVectit == myVect.end())    //<- Vector iterator not dereferenecable
    myVectit = myVect.begin();
```

The if statement is giving me an error "Vector iterator not dereferencable"

---

I found this to work after a lot of fudging around.

```
++myVectit ;
if(this->myVectit == this->myVect.end()){
    myVectit = myVect.begin();
}
```

Strangely the inverse doent work

```
if(this->myVectit != this->myVect.end()){
    ++myVectit ;
}
else
    myVectit = myVect.begin();
```

So im left with two questions. What is the major difference between the first attempt I made and the second using "this->".

second why doesnt the inverse of my solution work?

Answer (score 3):

`myVectit++;` as you have it in your [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26747004/1), is undefined behavior, since

```
 vector< myObj >::iterator myVectit;
```

isn't properly initialized at this point.

Your code should rather look something like

```
 vector< myObj > myVect;
 vector< myObj >::iterator myVectit = myVect.begin(); // <<< Initialize your iterator
                                                      //     properly

 if(myVectit != myVect.end()) { // Test for in range
     ++myVectit; // Safely increment
 }
 else {
     myVectit = myVect.begin(); // Wrap around
 }
```

Even if you had initialized `myVectit` correctly elsewhere, you should test against `myVectit != myVect.end()` **before** incrementing.

Comment: Testing through the vector I can see that line works fine. I may have left out headers but moving the iterator through the vector works fine. Is when I get to the end is the issue.

Comment: @RobMcNeil When you're incrementing the iterator, it's completely unrelated to your `myVect` instance. Believe me, it's UB! That doesn't necessarily mean your program would crash immediately or something.

Comment: @RobMcNeil How can "moving the iterator through the vector" work when the iterator never pointed to the vector to begin with?

Comment: It was pointed to the begining of the vector elsewhere. I will add the edit for clarity.

Comment: @RobMcNeil The principle still stands.

Comment: I agree with your concept partly. Incrementing it first woks better though. I believe it is because .begin() returns the pointer to the  empty object at the end not the last filled one. Could I implement something like if(myVectit == (myVect.end() - 1)) {myVectit = myVect.begin();}

Comment: @RobMcNeil _"Incrementing it first woks better though."_ Certainly not, having an empty vector, incrementing is UB again.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I understand what you are saying. Would it be smarter to this effect?    if( (this->myVectit + 1) ==( this->myVect.end()  ){
      myVectit = myVect.begin();
}
else
      ++myVectit ;

Comment: @RobMcNeil Let's look at the case of an empty vector again: `myVect.begin()` equals `myVect.end()`, now think about your condition in `if( (this->myVectit + 1) ==( this->myVect.end() )`. Do you think this will work?

Comment: Ah I see what you are getting at. I hadnt been concerned about an empty vector yet. I will have to modify the function to account for  that situation. My main concern was mot going past the end when the vector already contained objects.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when v.begin() <= it < v.end() and the iterator is in a valid state 
You should be good to use it.

A side note - I recommend using auto instead of std::vector::iterator

As of
1. Less typing 
2. You must initialize it, and you wouldn't have had the case of UB the code has.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I found increments the it and then checks to see if it is the end of the vector.

```
++myVectit ;
if(this->myVectit == this->myVect.end()){
myVectit = myVect.begin();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer and comments: This code is wrong, and calls undefined behavior, in case of an empty `std::vector<>`.